# Is this function bounded below?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let a bounded open set $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^N$ be given. Let $f$: $\Omega\to (0,+\infty]$ be given and we assume $f$ is locally integrable and there exists a constant $C>0$ so that 
$$
M(f)(x)\leq Cf(x)\tag 1
$$
for all $x\in\Omega$, where $M(f)$ denotes the maximal function of $f$ defined by
$$
M(f)(x):=\sup_{x\in B}\frac{1}{|B|}\int_Bf(y)dy.
$$

My question: can we prove that $f$ is bounded below by a positive constant? i.e., $f\geq c$ for some $c>0$.

---

Update: Please see below for a nice counter example by @zhw. Also, I think if instead of $f$: $\Omega\to (0,+\infty]$, I define $f$: $\mathbb R\to(0,+\infty]$, then the function $f$ should be bounded below by a positive constant in $\Omega$.

Here is my prove: since $\Omega$ is bounded, so $\bar \Omega$ is closed an bounded and hence compact. Thus we could cover $\bar\Omega$ by finitely many balls $(B_i)_{0\leq i\leq M}$. $(B_i)$ also covers $\Omega$. Thus, for any $x\in\Omega$, we have there exists $0\leq i\leq M$ so that $x\in B_i$ and by $(1)$ we have 
$$
f(x)\geq CM(f)(x)\geq C\frac{1}{|B_i|}\int_{B_i}f(y)dy\geq C\min_{0\leq j\leq M}\frac{1}{|B_j|}\int_{B_j}f(y)dy>0
$$
since $f$ is positive over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: You want $f$ locally integrable on all of $\mathbb R ^N?$

Comment: @zhw only in $\Omega$.

Comment: How do you define the maximal function then? What if $\Omega$ has measure $0$? Is $\Omega$ even measurable?

Comment: @zhw. sorry for confusion before. I added the definition of maximal function. Also, $\Omega$ is open and has a positive measure, otherwise we have nothing to prove.

Comment: How can you integrate over all such $B$ if $f$ is only defined on $\Omega$? Do you only consider $B$ contained in $\Omega$?

Comment: Presumably the notation means to take the supremum over all balls $B$ contained in $\Omega$ that contain $x$. (To the OP: you can't necessarily cover an open set by finitely many balls.)

Comment: Hmmm. Take $N=1$ and $\Omega=(0,1)$ and $f(x)=x$. Then $M(f)(x)=x$ for all $x$, right? So $C=1$ is acceptable, but $f$ is not bounded below by any positive constant.

Comment: @GregMartin No, $Mf(x) \ge 1/2$ everywhere, because you can always take $B_x$ to be the whole interval.

Comment: @zhw. how about we take $B=\Omega$ and hence we can show that $M(f)(x)$ has a uniform positive lower bound since $f>0$. Then by $(1)$ we done.

Comment: If $\Omega$ is an interval, then yes, but if $\Omega$ is not connected, then no. This is just for $N=1.$

Comment: The problem is that you haven't defined what you mean by $B$. I assume you mean *balls centered at $x$*; if this is the case, then your calculation isn't relevant. If you mean *open sets containing $x$* then that's a different story. Which is the right definition?

Comment: @GregMartin I assumed your definition above, $x\in B_x \subset \Omega, B_x$ not necessarily centered at $x.$

Comment: Ok, I see that there are "maximal functions" and "centered maximal functions" out there; the latter is more intuitive to me, but I grant that the uncentered version ($x$ doesn't have to be the center of $B$) is probably what's meant here. (OP: could have been clearer!)

Comment: @GregMartin Sorry for confusion! I mean the for any open ball contains $x$, not necessary centered at $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample when $N=2:$ Let $\Omega$ be the open triangle with vertices $(0,0), (1,0),(1,1).$ Define $f(x,y)=x.$ Suppose $(x,y)\in \Omega.$ Consider a ball $B=B((a,b),r) \subset \Omega,$ with $(x,y) \in B$ and $a\ge x.$ Then a little geometry shows $r\le a/2.$ Thus $a-x \le a/2 \implies a/2 \le x.$ It follows that the largest value $f$ can take in $B$ is $\le a+r \le 3a/2 \le 3x/2.$ Therefore the average of $f$ over this ball is $\le 3x/2.$ If we took $B$ to have its center to the left of $x,$ then it's obvious the average of $f$ over $B$ is $\le x.$ It follows that $Mf(x,y)\le 3x/2 = (3/2)f(x,y).$ But clearly $\inf_{\Omega} f = 0,$ so we have a counterexample.

Comment: Nice example! I also updated my post, could you have a look? Thank you!